# Determine JNI/JVM version before launching JVM

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a C application that uses JNI to embed a JVM and supports various Java versions.
The app runs on linux, OSX and windows.

At the moment it allows providing JVM args via environment variables, but I'd like to make it smarter.

Unfortunately, I need to set some of the VM arguments differently depending on the Java version.

I could get the version if I had a `JNIEnv*` using [`GetVersion`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#getversion) - but by the time I've got a `JNIEnv*`, I've already spun up a JVM and its too late. (And you can't shut down and restart a new JVM.)

It looks like  [`JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html#jni_getdefaultjavavminitargs) would do the trick - but while it compiles OK I can't get a sensible answer from it. For example, using Java 9:

```
    JavaVMInitArgs vmArgs;
    vmArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
    if (JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&vmArgs)!=JNI_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs failed!\n");
    };
    fprintf(stderr, "Query with version = %x\n", JNI_VERSION_1_2);
    fprintf(stderr, "JAVA version = %x\n", vmArgs.version);
```

prints

```
Query with version = 10002
JAVA version = 10002
```

i.e. it hasn't updated the version.

Is there a way to get this information (in a cross-platform way)? Am I doing something wrong in my use of `JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to base yourself on the **JNI version** as opposed to the **JVM version**?

Comment: Is "inspecting the output of `java -version`" an acceptable cross-platform solution for getting the JVM version?

Comment: @Botje it seems there's a pretty decent mapping between highest JNI version and the JVM version.  (Though I can't find an official source for that).

Comment: @Botje There's no reason the java library I've loaded (from LD_LIBRARY_PATH etc) needs to match the version of java in the PATH. So it's certainly not as trivial as just parsing `java -version`.

Comment: *"you can't shut down and restart a new JVM"* Why not?

Comment: @Olivier - The reason comes from two parts of the docs in the "Invocation API" (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html). 1. You're not allowed to have more than one JVM at a time (from docs on `JNI_CreateJavaVM`) 2. you can't destroy a JVM (the notes on `JNI_DestroyJavaVM` says that "As of JDK/JRE 1.1.2 unloading of the VM is not supported.")

Comment: Then the only way is to start another process that will retrieve the version. You could cache the result to avoid the cost.

Comment: @Olivier "Then the **only** way is to start another process that will retrieve the version".  I can think of two ways that might work - but they are painful to implement. The first is to determine the path to the loaded `libjvm.so` then back-out the java version from files in that directory. The second is to create a table of which JVM version certain symbols were first available in the libjvm.so and try loading them using `dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT,name)` - for example looking at the symbols I can see that `JVM_ClassLoaderDepth` was added between versions 9.0.x and 10.0.x.

Comment: out of curiosity, what happens when you call `JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs` after you initialize the struct with the *highest* version you support?

Answer (score 3):

Why not do the simplest thing first and just start a JVM in a separate process to figure out the JVM version:

```
int fds[2];
pipe(fds);
if (fork() == 0) { // child
  close(fds[0]);
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
  vm_args.options = nullptr;
  vm_args.nOptions = 0;
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = true;

  JNIEnv *env = nullptr;
  jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);

  jclass cls_Runtime = env->FindClass("java/lang/Runtime");
  jmethodID mid_version = env->GetStaticMethodID("version", "()Ljava/lang/Runtime$Version;");
  jobject obj_Version = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(cls_Runtime, mid_getVersion);

  jclass cls_Version = env->GetObjectClass(obj_Version);
  jmethodID mid_toString = env->getMethodID(cls_Version, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
  jstring str_Version = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(obj_version, mid_toString);

  const char *version = env->GetStringUTFChars(str_Version, null);

  write(fds[1], version, env->GetStringUTFLength(str_Version));
  exit(0);
} else if (fork() > 0) { // parent
  close(fds[1]);
  char version[100];
  int size = read(fds[0], version, 100);
  close(fds[0]);
  version[size] = '\0'; 
  // continue initialization
} else { // error }
```

Instead of calling `toString` you could of course just grab `feature()` instead.

Comment: I did consider something like this. And it's not too bad on linux and OSX. But AFAIK there is no fork in windows. (Not insurmountable - but more code). And fork has its own issues in complex applications - you need to ensure it occurs before any threads have started, and any `atexit` handlers installed - I think there are other limitations too. Either way, spawning a process seems like overkill for something that feels like its should just be as simple as `char * version = JNI_GetJVMVersion()`.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Even easier - figure out your arguments after creating the JVM, then call `execve()` with the new args.  No need to fork and pass arguments between processes.  And Windows supports `execve()`.  Use the same `argv[0]` so you're just re-exec'ing the same binary.  Just make sure you parse the args so you don't fall into an `execve()` infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish between JNI and JVM. Each JVM version supports a set of JNI API depending on its version (see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#version-information for the latest list). When you request the activation of the JVM you have to set the minimum version of JNI your application is written for; the C linkage is incremental, e.g. the [GetModule](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#getmodule) is available from version 9. If you call [CreateJavaVM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html#jni_createjavavm) with an highest version of JNI than the one the JVM supports, the API returns JNI_EVERSION.

If the arguments of your application depends on the JVM version the JNI version is unuseful: the latest JNI version is 10 and it is the same from JRE 10 to JRE 18.

To be able to invoke JNI API you have to load the JVM main library. When you load the JVM library you decide which version of JVM you will use and consequently the JNI version. A system can have multiple installed JVMs, one is the default while other can be accessed using the path to jvm.dll, libjvm.so, etc. Generally, the version of the JVM is written in the path and it depends on many things like the specification, the build, the vendor, the platform. This is an output of apt:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.10+9-0ubuntu1~20.04, or
sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-13-jre-headless  # version 13.0.4+8-1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-14-jre-headless  # version 14.0.2+12-1~20.04
```

You can parse the path of the JVM library trying to identify the JRE specification (8, 11, 13, ...) then you can call [CreateJavaVM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html#jni_createjavavm) with the arguments your application needs for that version.